# C# Index 0 is either negative or above rows count with DataRowView - why?

Tags: c#, dataset, datarow

I know this is a classic error but I'm not aware of what is happening.

I have a DataSet and then I evaluate if it is filled before moving on, like this:

```
if (
                    ds == null
                    || ds.Tables == null
                    || ds.Tables[0] == null
                    || ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 0
                    )
                    return null;

                
                DataRowView prd = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView[0];
```

And then this last row breaks with the following error:

```
Type : System.IndexOutOfRangeException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : Index 0 is either negative or above rows count.
Source : System.Data
Help link : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : System.Data.DataRow GetRow(Int32)
HResult : -2146233080
Stack Trace :
   at System.Data.DataView.GetRow(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.DataView.get_Item(Int32 recordIndex)
```

Given the evaluations I've made, how is this even possible? I was unable to reproduce this...

Comment: Between `ds.Tables == null` and `ds.Tables[0] == null`, you don't check that `ds.Tables.Count == 0`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply but how is that possible? I mean it calls a stored procedure before, it runs always even if it doesn't return any data, it should have tables right?

Comment: Requires debugging details.

Comment: As a side note: the Tables property will never be `null`, so that check is superfluous.

Comment: Why not check the actual property you're going to be calling (i.e., `DefaultView`)?

Comment: You probably want to read up on the null propagation operators in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-.  You're code would be a lot simpler with a few `?.` and `?[0]` operators in there

Answer (score 0):

This is curious:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 0
```

I don't recall ever seeing, and have trouble imagining how a collection could contain a negative number of items.. But anyway

```
DataRowView prd = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView[0];
```

This can still blow up even after all the checks you've made, because it demands the first row from the view, which might not be a thing even if the table has rows (the view may have a filter that excludes all of the table rows).. Perhaps you meant `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];` ?

Answer (score 0):

You must check DefaultView. It may be null or empty